# #Error in access report on empty record/0 value Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, report, calculated-field

I keep getting an #Error on a textbox which is filled using a calculation on query/database fields while I am checking if the value is greater than 0.

So I got the following subform:

[image]

In this subform the user inserts his products, after the previous filled line the subform always generates a second (empty) one.

The inserted products are being displayed in a report:

[image]

As you can see, the 'empty' line generates errors. I think this is because the line on which it gives the error is a calculated field.

I though to fix it doing a if greater than 0 check on one of the calculated fields. To make it a bit clearer oppervlakte = area which calcualates it by multiplying the `width * height * product count` - all these fields are 0 (or NULL?) on the empty line.

This is what I try'd to do on the #error field:

```
=IIf([BreedteCoating]>0;[BreedteCoating]*[HoogteCoating]*[AantalEenheden]/1000000;"")
```

So if the width (Breedte) is greater than 0 then calculate the field else just leave it empty. This doesn't seem to work though.

Any clue how I can make this calculate field work (no #Error) if the values are 0 or NULL?

Comment: try nz([BreedteCoating],0) > 0;....

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The inline NZ just doesn't accept the NZ function whatsoever (can move to another line in the textbox properties. Adjusted it like this `=Iif(Nz([BreedteCoating],0) > 0;[BreedteCoating]*[HoogteCoating]*[AantalEenheden]/1000000); "")` When I click the properties away after the adjustment it just turns back to the old IIF.

Comment: NZ returns a defined value if an argument is null. so your if condition would look like . IIF(nz(argument,0) > 0; true value; else value). in your last try, you have an extra ")" hence its reverting back to the last working code.

Comment: Hmm missed the last `)` but still it doesn't accept it even if I remove the `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it doing the calculation a little bit different. Did the calculation in the query of the report itself, this way I can just use the calculation field directly in my report which also handles null/0 values correctly.